# If Bt is a Brownian movement. Show that for any t and s, P (Bt> Bs) = 1/2.

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

My teacher said it was because of the symmetry but I don't really understand ):
somebody can help me?

Comment: Try reviewing the properties that define the Brownian motion. You can reduce to the case $s = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

$B_t > B_s$ if and only if $B_t - B_s >0 $. Hence, $\mathbb{P}(B_t - B_s >0) = \mathbb{P}(B_t > B_s)$. Now, $B_t - B_s$ has distribution $\mathcal{N}(0,t-s)$, (by definition of Brownian motion) which is symmetric around the origin.